# How to prevent editing of generated Javascript files in a TypeScript project?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, typescript

Is it possible in a Visual Studio 2012 project to enforce a rule that prevents developers from trying to directly edit (by accident/old habit) the JavaScript files generated by the TypeScript files?

I have a project with a lot of TypeScript files that have in turn generated a lot of JavaScript files that have to be included in the project.  However, I find myself selecting the JavaScript files out of habit rather than selecting the Typescript version of file to do my editing.  I'd like to prevent this.  Because these TypeScript/JavaScript files are linked in from elsewhere, I can't seem to nest them.

The project is a Windows Store app with WinJS.  It has three different Windows Store projects in it and a set of shared solution folders that include the bulk of the TypeScript/JavaScript files which are linked into the projects using the syntax below in the project files:

```
<Content Include="..\Shared\**\*.*">
  <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

This allows me to include all files in the Shared directory and sub-directories as automatically linked files.  It's really handy for sharing linked files, but mean I can nest individual files because the recursive file linking would get broken.

My source control is git.  So I suppose there might be an option to prevent editing the .js files in git?  Looking for suggestions.

Comment: An alternative would be to nest files...which doesn't exist as functionality yet.  You could probably [create a VSC extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview) to do this, or just [vote and wait](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/8239908-add-ability-to-nest-files-under-a-parent-file).

Answer (score 7):

> So I suppose there might be an option to prevent editing the .js files in git?

We have the .js files *excluded* from the repo using `.gitignore`. These js files are built again as a part of build / deploy.

This is similar to the manner you wouldn't include `*.exe` / `*.dll` files in your git repo.

Comment: You can now use the VSCode option to hide gitignore files from the explorer.
"explorer.excludeGitIgnore": true

Answer (score 1):

I recently started using Visual Studio code.  In the user settings you can hide the js files entirely.

Select:

File | Preferences | User Settings

add the following to the right side editor (you can't modify the default settings).

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true,
    "**/*.js": true,
    "**/*.js.map":true
}
```

I am not sure if you need the first two lines, but they were in the default settings that I just copied over.  Obviously, When you want to see JavaScript files again just switch that true to false.

Comment: This seems like it's the most efficient workaround for this clutter until nesting is implemented, either as an extension or in the base.  While `.gitignore` is great for interacting with git, that won't prevent you from accidentally modifying a `.js` file and corrupting your dev env, even if just locally/temporarily.  True, you just have to open and save the `.ts` again, but it's very easy to do this inadvertently.  While this approach is not 100% foolproof, it works well for me.

Comment: @EricLease thanks for the reminder about *.js.map.  I had that in my project, but forgot to come back here and add it to the answer. +1 to you Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a way to "block" editing directly the JS files, since they are in your project.

You could use Gulp, for example, to watch all your files and generate the JS file from its TS file if there's been a modification on a JS file.

It's not perfect, but it would prevent a developper from typing stuff in the JS file.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch

Answer (score 0):

To hide files from both your VSCode explorer UI and Git, put build files/folders in your .gitignore and then enable the "explorer.excludeGitIgnore" option in VSCode.