# WebStorm: How to disable editing of generated JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, ide, typescript, webstorm

In our TypeScript project, I often find myself viewing the generated JavaScript (*.js) file, which are very similar to the TypeScript (*.ts) file, and try to edit them, only to find out that when the TypeScript file is transpiled, my changes are discarded.
Is there a way to configure WebStorm to warn me before I try to edit a *.js file in my src directory?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380302/how-to-prevent-editing-of-generated-javascript-files-in-a-typescript-project) is a similar question for Visual Studio (currently unanswered).

Comment: Try adding them as Libraries.

Comment: You could compile your js files into a separate folder and then Right click -> mark directory as -> Excluded. That will keep Webstorm from offering the js files as places where things are defined. You might end up not opening the files as often as you do now and thereby end up in a ts file more. It's not a full solution but might help a little.

Comment: What do I do if the .js are in the same directory as the .ts files?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should hide them. Check [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/04/intellij-idea-does-not-show-some-files-know-the-hiding-places/).